# exec doesn't pick up variables from closure

Tags: python, closures, exec, python-2.x

I'm a little curious why the following code raises a `NameError`.

```
>>> s = """
... foo = [1,2,3]
... def bar():
...    return foo[1]
... """
>>> namespace = {}
>>> exec(s, {'__builtins__': None}, namespace)
>>> print namespace
{'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': <function bar at 0x7f79871bd0c8>}
>>> namespace['bar']()
```

At the normal interpreter level, we can find `foo` in `bar.func_globals` or `bar.func_closure` if in a function.  I guess I'm wondering why `namespace['bar']` doesn't put `foo` in `func_closure` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the answer was there all along in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement):

> If two separate objects are given as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

Since I'm passing in both `globals` and `locals`, it executes as if it were in a class.

```
class Foo(object):
    foo = [1,2,3]
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
       return foo[1]
```

not surprisingly doesn't work either :).

For anyone interested in a workaround, you can inject `namespace` back into `namespace['bar'].func_globals`<sup>1</sup> ([inspired by this](http://helduel.blogspot.com/2011/01/injecting-mock-objects-into-functions.html)):

```
>>> namespace['bar'].func_globals.update(namespace)
>>> namespace['bar']()
2
```

Nice.

<sup><sup>1</sup>It would be `namespace['bar'].__globals__.update` on python3.x</sup>